# Multi size queue without malloc

Tags: c, queue

I am interested in build a queue that could receive different but defined sizes. Let's say, with 8, 16 and 32 elements and I want to do it without use malloc. 
Well, it would be easy if I create 3 different queues but I don't want to do this, I want to use the same functions and just define the three types.

My problem is exactly this, I have three places in my code that I would like to use a queue, but those cases would use queues with different sizes and I know what size it is. I don't want to create three group of functions and structs to make this queue, I would like to just create three structs and use the same functions. Also, I can't use malloc, because it is a embedded application.

I want to receive ideas of how to create something as abstract type of C++ in C. It could solve my problem.

Is there any way to to this?

Thanks!

Comment: In C++ you could probably create a template class for this.

Comment: but I wanna do this in C.

Comment: Why don't you use stack variables (array), if you know the exact size?

Comment: Revert to array instead of queue and your problem would be solved!

Comment: Perhaps you should add example code for a queue with just one sized element. That would make the question much easier to answer.

Comment: I can't see how if I want to use queue and array could solve my problem.

Comment: You probably want a byte buffer area for a queue, where you store items as raw byte blobs, much like you would if you wrote them to raw binary file.

Comment: Because it creates the object with the exact size you want without using malloc. It is the same as malloc without malloc.

Comment: I want three different size queues. It's what I want. If I could use malloc it would be easy but I can't.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly now you see the abstract of my question. I would like to know if, knowing the sizes in compiling time, I could create those queues without malloc.

Comment: Or in a different way, if knowing the sizes, I could use the same function to access different structs...I'd like to receive ideas using pointers or maybe function pointers that could solve this problem.

Comment: "queue size", do you mean queue total memory use, max item count or item size or something else? How do you create the queue object, where is it (heap? stack? static data?) and in what scope does it exist (global, main, some other func)?

Comment: Queue size I mean max item count and also max memory use. This queue will be created with the program as global structs. That is it, a queue is an array with some functions and data associated...I'd like to define different sizes to those arrays.

Comment: Why are you concerned not to use `malloc()`?  There are a number of straight-forward ways to do it using `malloc()`.  An option to consider is simply always using size 32, but having a parameter to the queue that limits the size to some smaller number (8 or 16).  A lot depends on the size of the elements.  If they're pointers, the wasted space is minimal.  If the elements are each hundreds of bytes, maybe this isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered how to do it. Maybe I've expressed it wrong but this solution that I have reached solves my problem:

Source file:

```
#include "Fila.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Fila_Init(Fila_t * fila, const uint32_t qtdLinhas, const uint32_t qtdColunas, char ** buffer)
{
    fila->qtdLinhas = qtdLinhas;
    fila->qtdColunas = qtdColunas;
    fila->head = 0;
    fila->tail = 0;
    fila->tamanho = 0;
    fila->linhas = buffer;
    uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < fila->qtdLinhas; i++)
        memset(fila->linhas[i], FILA_CARACTERE, FILA_COLUNAS);
}

void Fila_Enfileira(Fila_t * fila, int tamDado, const char * dado)
{
    if(tamDado > FILA_COLUNAS)
        tamDado = FILA_COLUNAS;

    if (FILA_TAIL == FILA_HEAD && (fila->tamanho + 1) > fila->qtdLinhas)
            fila->head++;

    memset(fila->linhas[FILA_TAIL], FILA_CARACTERE, FILA_COLUNAS);
    fila->linhas[FILA_TAIL][tamDado] = '\0';

    memcpy(fila->linhas[FILA_TAIL_INC], dado, tamDado);

    if(fila->tamanho < fila->qtdLinhas)
        fila->tamanho++;
}

char * Fila_Desenfileira(Fila_t * fila)
{
    if(Fila_TemProximo(fila))
        fila->tamanho--;

    return fila->linhas[FILA_HEAD_INC];
}

inline char * Fila_Primeiro(Fila_t * fila)
{
    return fila->linhas[FILA_HEAD];
}

inline bool Fila_TemProximo(Fila_t * fila)
{
    return (fila->tamanho > 0);
}

void Fila_Imprime(Fila_t * fila)
{
  int tamanho = fila->tamanho;
  int cabeca = fila->head;
  while(tamanho > 0)
  {
    printf("%s\n", fila->linhas[(cabeca++ % fila->qtdLinhas)]);
    tamanho--;
  }
}
```

Header file:

```
/*
 * Fila.h
 *
 *  Created on: 18/06/2013
 *      Author: Leandro
 */

#ifndef FILA_H_
#define FILA_H_

#include "types.h"
#include <stdint.h>

#define FILA_COLUNAS (fila->qtdColunas)
#define FILA_CARACTERE 0xff
#define FILA_TAIL (fila->tail % fila->qtdLinhas)
#define FILA_HEAD (fila->head % fila->qtdLinhas)
#define FILA_TAIL_INC (fila->tail++ % fila->qtdLinhas)
#define FILA_HEAD_INC (fila->head++ % fila->qtdLinhas)

typedef struct {
    uint32_t qtdLinhas;
    uint32_t qtdColunas;
    uint32_t head;
    uint32_t tail;
    uint32_t tamanho;
    char ** linhas;
} Fila_t;

void Fila_Init(Fila_t * fila, const uint32_t qtdLinhas, const uint32_t qtdColunas, char ** buffer);
void Fila_Enfileira(Fila_t * fila, int tamDado, const char * dado);
char * Fila_Desenfileira(Fila_t * fila);
bool Fila_TemProximo(Fila_t * fila);
char * Fila_Primeiro(Fila_t * fila);
void Fila_Imprime(Fila_t * fila);

#endif /* FILA_H_ */
```

and also, tester file:

```
#include "Fila.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Fila_t testeStatic()
{
    static char ele[8][512];
    const int c = sizeof(ele[0])/sizeof(ele[0][0]);
    const int l = sizeof(ele)/c;

    printf("Tamanho da matriz: %d bytes.\n", c*l*sizeof(char));
    char* ele2[c];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
        ele2[i] = ele[i];

    Fila_t fila;
    Fila_Init(&fila, l, c, ele2);

    printf("Tamanho da matriz de ponteiros na fila: %d bytes.\n", sizeof(fila) - 5*sizeof(uint32_t));
    printf("Tamanho da fila: %d bytes.\n", sizeof(fila));
    printf("Tamanho final de uma fila [8][512]: %d\n", c*l*sizeof(char)+sizeof(fila));
    printf("Overhead de apenas 24 bytes ou %f por cento.\n", (float)((sizeof(fila) * 100))/(c*l*sizeof(char)));
    return fila;
}
void testaFila(Fila_t * fila)
{
    char texto[20];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        Fila_Enfileira(fila, sprintf(texto, "Entrada [%d]", i), texto);

    while (Fila_TemProximo(fila))
        printf("%s\n", Fila_Desenfileira(fila));
}

int main()
{
    Fila_t fila = testeStatic();
    testaFila(&fila);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for it's in portuguese language, but I'm sure it'll be helpfull even in my language.
A special thanks to @Doug Currie for the help and patience. If someone needs help understanding this code, It'll be a pleasure to explain. I have also created this [project](https://code.google.com/p/qwoma) on google code and it would be a great pleasure to receive ideas and critics from you!

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. Here a couple...

1. Include the size of the queue in the queue header; the functions that access the queue use the size from the header to limit the number of entries
2. Pass the queue size as an argument to the functions that manage the queue

The first option is less error prone, but takes an extra header field.

The structs would be defined as

```
static struct s_que8
{
   int in;
   int out;
   int size; // for option 1
   int elements[8]; // or whatever size you like
} que8;
```

In any case the queues will require initialization of the `in` and `out` indices, and the `size` value for option 1. If your queue protocol is that `in == out` means the queue is empty, you can just set `in = out = 0;` to initialize them.

ADDENDUM

For elements that are static strings, here are some specific structure declarations:

```
static struct s_que8
{
   int in;
   int out;
   int size; // for option 1
   char * elements[8]; // for pointers to static strings
} que8;
```

or

```
static struct s_que8
{
   int in;
   int out;
   int size; // for option 1
   char elements[8][MAX_STRING_SIZE]; // for strings stored in the queue
} que8;
```

Change `8` to suit your specific queue size.

The corresponding "generic" typedefs would be:

```
typedef struct s_queX
{
   int in;
   int out;
   int size; // for option 1
   char * elements[]; // for pointers to static strings
} Queue;
```

or

```
typedef struct s_queX
{
   int in;
   int out;
   int size; // for option 1
   char elements[][MAX_STRING_SIZE]; // for strings stored in the queue
} Queue;
```

Comment: Ok, but, how would be a function like dequeue(Queue * queue) ?? That's, what I would pass as argument to this function?

Comment: For option 2 you'd pass `size` as in `dequeue(Queue * queue, int size)`

Comment: what would be Queue in this case? A pointer to what struct, s_que8, 16 or 32?

Comment: You can use a `typedef struct s_queX { int in; int out; int size; int elements[]; } Queue;` since C permits the last element of a struct to be an array with an open size.

Comment: Even if my elements are strings?

Comment: How to do this @Doug Currie, could you give me some example?

Comment: Are you queuing pointers to static strings, or are you dynamically creating strings? Or are you really queueing characters? The best approach will depend on your application.

Comment: See addendum for string data.

Comment: Is there like this, any way to decide the string size?

Comment: You must limit the string size in the application to avoid consuming too much memory; the size you choose is application specific.

Comment: But could I create different sizes to string and use them as possible sizes?

Comment: Sure, you can have variable sized strings as long as they fit within the (arbitrary but predetermined) `MAX_STRING_SIZE` -- use a terminating NUL (`\0') character to indicate the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TAILQ with free_elements, an every time you want a element you may remove it from the free_elements queue, use it, and later insert it back to the list.

For the malloc problem, you need to initialize your queue with a static memory.

Example:

```
static struct my_element free_elements_array[TOTAL_ELEMENTS];

extern int my_queue_init(void)
{
    int i;
    TAILQ_INIT(my_queue_head);

    for (i=0; i<TOTAL_ELEMENTS;i++)
        TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(my_queue_head, &free_elements_array[i]);

    return 0;
}

extern struct my_element *get_element(void)
{
    struct my_element *element;
    element = TAILQ_LAST(my_queue_head)
    if (element)
    {
        TAILQ_REMOVE(my_queue_head, element)
    }
    return element.
}
```

TAILQ is just a suggestion, and the macros in my code are not complete, use only as example. For more information about them and others queue see http://linux.die.net/man/3/queue.