# Error in execution time with MinGw

Tags: c, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have this function that works fine:

```
void testeStatic2()
{
    static char elementos[8][128];
    const int qtdCol = 128;
    const int qtdLn = 8;

    printf("\n");

    char* pLinhas[qtdCol];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < qtdLn; i++)
        pLinhas[i] = elementos[i];

    Fila_Init(&TELIT_dadosRecebidos, qtdLn, qtdCol, pLinhas);
}
```

I couldn't recreate this code in a simpler way, so, if possible, ignoring the rest of the code, the problem is that although it works, if I take out the `printf("\n")` it gives me an execution time error. Has anyone any idea about it?

Thanks...

Comment: Could you explain what the code is supposed to do and what the error is?

Comment: What is the content of `Fila_Init`?

Comment: This is a execution time error, and I don't know how to debug with eclipse...the code initialize a queue but it's hard to explain well...I'll try to create a reduced code with this error.

Comment: Here I put the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531821/multi-size-queue-without-malloc

Comment: But I'd like to know why it works with printf and doesn't without...

Comment: It should't give an error (in this case), but are you sure you didn't mean to declare `pLinhas` as `char* pLinhas[qtdLn]`?

Comment: Well, it's an array of char pointers with 8 pointers.

Comment: As you have declared it now is an array of char pointers with 128 pointers (qtdCol). And in the for loop you go from 0 to the number of lines (qtdLn-1) and you assign to the first 8 of them (out of the 128 allocated) a reference to `elementos`.

Comment: hummm, I thought it was an array with no defined size to pointers to arrays of 128 chars.

Comment: I must create an char** from this char*[128]...how can I do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as `array with no defined size to pointers to arrays of 128 chars`. You can use `char **` in the following way `char **pLinhas; 
pLinhas = malloc(qtdLn * sizeof(char*)); 
for (i = 0; i < qtdLn; i++)
   pLinhas[i] = elementos[i];`
But I don't understand why would you want to create different references to some buffers you already have allocated. Please provide more details regarding the purpose of your code.

Comment: So, I would like to just use elementos but I always get type warnings. Anyway, I would like to create a queue os strings that I could pass the buffer where I will put the data and that I could use the same struct and functions to different size of buffers without use malloc. You can see that is works fine with 'printf' but gets wrong when I remove it. I need to use it without malloc because it is embedded.

Comment: I found the error...the problem is solved putting `pLinhas` as static.

Answer (score 0):

Just making `pLinhas` as `static` makes it to work fine. I suppose the problem was reference to nonexistent pointers after the end of function scope. So, this code was tested and works!

```
void FilaInit()
{   int i = 0;
    static char elementos[8][128];
    static char * pLinhas[8];

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        pLinhas[i] = &elementos[i][0];

    Fila_Init(&TELIT_dadosRecebidos, 8, 128, pLinhas);
}
```

A detail is that pLinhas is an array of pointers to char, an array of pointers to strings. Its size is 8*4 bytes. Other point is that I must to use constant integer to declare pLinhas.

I would like to emphasize this solution...I have searched a lot this kind of structured data. It's very interesting in cases where you cannot use malloc, like embedded applications, but need to create more than one queue with different sizes.

For those who want to use this solution, I've created this project on google code: [Qwoma](https://code.google.com/p/qwoma/). It would be a great pleasure to receive critics and ideas to this simple project.

Thanks everyone!